# .Net Architecture suggestion; Start process from web

Tags: c#, .net, architecture, windows-services

I'm working on a project that consists of a web application where users can start long process of generating different types of files.
User wont be able to download the files, only can start the process and the files will be located on the server and this process could take several hours.

My Idea to solve this its a MVC App that is communicate with a windows service and this service start the file generation process.

I have some concerns about this.

1. based on your experience, do you think that is the best way to solve the problem?
2. What is the best and easiest way to communicate the web app and the windows service? this is a one way communication, web to service.
3. About the windows services; should the service do all the processes? or maybe its better if the service only execute console applications that do the generation o the different type of files.

I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Since Web API can be self-hosted in any process and a Windows service isn't an exception, I would recommend hosting both HTTP API and the long process thing in the same Windows service.

- Use [OWIN/Katana to host your Web API.](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/hosting-aspnet-web-api/use-owin-to-self-host-web-api)
- Use [Topshelf](http://topshelf-project.com/) to create your Windows service.

If you design and implement this Windows service using best practices, it should be a good solution, and you should think about how easy will be the deployment of your solution since you don't need IIS anymore.

Comment: What's the benefit of using OWIN self host over IIS+console apps in this case?

Answer (score 1):

I would go still with the IIS. This is because of its support. Have been using Web webservice to host long running background service for long time without issues. Only concern is to remove the default application recycling.
Of course your application will need to handle properly start/stop events.